# Cassandra filtering map and other collections

Tags: collections, cassandra, filtering, custom-data-type

I am trying to do the following.

```
Connected to DevCluster
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10.0.1695 | DSE 5.1.1 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.

user@cqlsh:test> desc table del28;

CREATE TABLE test.del28 (
    sno int PRIMARY KEY,
    dob date,
    name range_dates,
    ssss_details map<text, date>,
    ssss_range map<text, frozen<map<date, date>>> );

CREATE INDEX idx_ssss_range ON test.del28 (keys(ssss_range));
CREATE INDEX ssss_details_idx ON test.del28 (values(ssss_details));
CREATE INDEX ssss_range_idx ON test.del28 (values(ssss_range));

user@cqlsh:test> select * from del28;

 sno | dob  | name                                 | ssss_details                                 | ssss_range
-----+------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------
   5 | null | {start: 2014-03-05, end: 2018-04-05} |                        {'hello': 2014-05-05} | {'1': {2018-04-05: 2012-02-05}}
   8 | null | {start: 2018-03-04, end: 2018-08-02} |                       {'hello8': 2018-08-08} | {'8': {2018-08-08: 2012-02-08}}
   2 | null | {start: 2018-03-04, end: 2018-05-05} |                        {'hello': 2018-05-05} | {'1': {2018-07-08: 2018-09-01}}
   4 | null | {start: 2014-03-04, end: 2018-04-02} |                       {'hello1': 2014-05-02} | {'1': {2018-04-08: 2012-02-04}}
   7 | null | {start: 2014-03-04, end: 2018-04-02} | {'hello4': 2014-05-03, 'hello5': 2014-05-02} | {'2': {2018-04-08: 2012-02-04}}
   6 | null | {start: 2014-03-04, end: 2018-04-02} | {'hello2': 2014-05-02, 'hello3': 2014-05-03} | {'2': {2018-04-08: 2012-02-04}}
   9 | null | {start: 2014-03-04, end: 2018-04-02} | {'hello7': 2014-05-02, 'hello8': 2014-05-03} | {'2': {2018-04-08: 2012-02-04}}
   3 | null | {start: 2014-03-04, end: 2018-04-02} |                        {'hello': 2014-05-02} | {'1': {2018-04-08: 2012-02-04}}

(8 rows)
```

My question is, can I use Filters on ssss_range, if so how? If not what is the best way to save this data. Idea is, there is number or text followed by dates. Example house1: {2012-04-05: 2013-02-05}, house2:{2013-04-08: 2014-02-04}...... for one particular user and where dates are a set  and , explaining that person stayed on these times. I tried to split the dates in 'name' column. Still it did not work for me. Now there is lot of other info regarding this record. 
I should be able to query based on house1, house2 i.e. where aaa = 'house1', some thing like that. Also should be able query based on dates i.e. where from_date > '' and to_date < ''. Something like that.

I am okay to change the way data is changed if it can query a better way. Any type of collections or data types are fine. 
Please suggest the right approach.

Thanks